# Negative binomial distribution.Calculate the probability that exactly 12 packages are inspected.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, negative-binomial

In a shipment of 20 packages, 7 packages are damaged. The packages are randomly inspected, one at a time, without replacement, until the fourth damaged package is discovered.
Calculate the probability that exactly 12 packages are inspected.

I used negative binomial distribution, with $p=$ $\frac{7}{20}$,$r=4$ and $x=8$, where $r$ is the number of successes, $x$ is the number of failures before $r^{th}$ success and $p$ is the probability of success of a particular trial.

$p(x)  = 
\binom {r+x-1}{x}p^r(1-p)^x
$

$p(x=8)  = 
\binom {11}{8}(\frac{7}{20})^4(1-\frac{7}{20})^8=0.079
$

However the answer is 0.119. What have I done wrong?

Comment: The distribution is not negative binomial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distribution is *not* negative binomial, for in the negative binomial the trials are independent. Here we are not replacing after inspecting. The resulting distribution is sometimes called *negative hypergeometric*, but the term is little used.

We can use an analysis close in spirit to the one that leads to the negative binomial "formula." We get the $4$-th "success" on the $12$-th trial if we have exactly $3$ successes in the first $11$, and then a success.

There are $\binom{20}{11}$ equally likely ways to choose the first $11$ items. There are $\binom{7}{3}\binom{13}{8}$ ways to choose $3$ defective and $8$ good.

So the probability exactly $3$ of the first $11$ items are defective is $\dfrac{\binom{7}{3}\binom{13}{8}}{\binom{20}{11}}$.

Suppose we had $3$ defectives in the first $11$ trials. Then there are $9$ items left, of which $4$ are defective.  Thus the conditional probabilit that the $12$-th item is defective is $\frac{4}{9}$. Multiply.

Answer (score 0):

Take all possibilities of arranging 7 defective packages amongst 20.

The ones with fourth package on position 12 can be calculated by placing 3 packages among the first 11 and 3 among the last 8:

${{11}\choose{3}} * {{8}\choose{3}} / {{20}\choose{7}}$

(11 choose 3) * (8 choose 3)/(20 choose 7) = 0.11919504644